# sharing VBA variables between excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have one sheet with VBA code with many variables and constants and I would like to use those variables even in VBA code of another sheet. Unfortunately code is split between sheets and requires shared variables and constants as input parameters. Is it possible in VBA for excel?

Comment: You should declare the variable in module level .. as Public

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must declare variables as `Public variable [As type]`. As @matzone said, at module level, i.e., before any subs, functions or properties.

In case of variable duplication you must refer to it as `module.variable`, where *module* is module code name as `Sheet1` or `ThisWorkbook`.

Consider also the option of inserting a module in your VBA project to join all those shared variables (and functions, subs).

Answer (score 0):

`Public token As String` can access from other sheets, here token is variable